# Strange Autoref Countering of lstlisting

Tags: listings, autoref

I made a new listtype called *mycodes* and want to autoref to them. The problem is, when using autoref to a lstlisting-block the number of the listing is wrong!

---

**The code**

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[]{hyperref}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{frame=tb}
\usepackage{tocloft}


\newlistof{mycodes}{cod}{}
\newcommand{\mycodes}[2][]{
\refstepcounter{mycodes}
\par\noindent Code \thesection.\themycodes: #2\\
}

\addto\extrasgerman{\def\lstlistingautorefname{Codeexample}}


\begin{document}

\section{Kapitel 1}
\subsection{Unterkapitel 1.1}
\begin{lstlisting}[label=cod:Fun1_1]
    void Function()
\end{lstlisting}
\mycodes{Example of Code 1}

\begin{lstlisting}[label=cod:Fun1_2]
    void Function()
\end{lstlisting}
\mycodes{Example of Code 2}

\begin{lstlisting}[label=cod:Fun1_3]
    void Function()
\end{lstlisting}
\mycodes{Example of Code 3}

\autoref{cod:Fun1_1}\\
\autoref{cod:Fun1_2}\\
\autoref{cod:Fun1_3}\\

\end{document}
```

---

**The Output**

[image: ![LaTeX Output]

---

**Expected Output**

I would like to get the real number of the codeblock as also shown in the subcaption of the lstlistings. So something like:

```
Codeexample 1.1
Codeexample 1.2
Codeexample 1.3
```

How to do so?

Comment: the label is well before the \mycodes command, so how should it be able to store the number?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That's true :/ But I have no clue how to change this :(  I want to have the caption below the code and I can't use a label command inside the lstlisting, because its outputing the line number...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use caption and set the position to bottom:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[]{hyperref}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{frame=tb,captionpos=b}
\renewcommand\lstlistingname{Code}
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand\thelstlisting{\thesection.\arabic{lstlisting}}}

\addto\extrasgerman{\def\lstlistingautorefname{Codeexample}}


\begin{document}

\section{Kapitel 1}
\subsection{Unterkapitel 1.1}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Example of Code 1,label=cod:Fun1_1]
    void Function()
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Example of Code 2,label=cod:Fun1_2]
    void Function()
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Example of Code 3,label=cod:Fun1_3]
    void Function()
\end{lstlisting}

\autoref{cod:Fun1_1}\\
\autoref{cod:Fun1_2}\\
\autoref{cod:Fun1_3}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hmm, this is way too easy to get the exact result I wanted! :) Thank you VERY MUCH! You saved my day!

Comment: It also helped me change the format of the listing prefix caption.